# How to draw a rectangle for reciting tone in chant transcription in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to use LilyPond to transcribe chanted music using mostly modern notation.

I've read http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/learning/gregorian-transcription-template, which was quite helpful, but I can't figure out how to draw the solid rectangle to use for a reciting note, as in the photograph below.

Can anyone point me toward how I would draw a rectangle at a particular pitch to indicate a reciting tone in LilyPond?

[image: chant notation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an ugly workaround, based off of [this answer](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/defining-custom-note-heads-tp34608p34609.html) on the LilyPond listserv.

```
\version "2.19.63"

headLine = {
  \once \override NoteHead  #'stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
  \once \hide Stem
  \once \override NoteHead #'text = #(markup #:lower 0.5 ( #:concat (
    #:musicglyph "rests.M1" #:musicglyph "rests.M1" #:musicglyph "rests.M1"
    #:musicglyph "rests.M1" #:musicglyph "rests.M1" #:musicglyph "rests.M1"
    #:musicglyph "rests.M1" #:musicglyph "rests.M1" #:musicglyph "rests.M1" ) ) )
}

{
   e'4 g'4
   \headLine
   a'4
}
```

[image]

Note that `#:lower` was necessary since the given musicglyph is higher than expected; without this parameter, inputting `a'` results in the rests being placed at `b'`!

---

**EDIT:** Here's an alternative, much cleaner approach:

```
\version "2.19.63"

headLine = {
  \once \override NoteHead  #'stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
  \once \hide Stem
  \once \override NoteHead.text = \markup { \lower #0.5
    \filled-box #'(0 . 6) #'(0 . 1) #0 } %% adjust x distance of 6 as necessary
}

{
   e'4 g'4
   \headLine
   a'4
}
```

[image]